# Coin minable from browser

Tags: mining-theory

I was wondering if there is a coin that can be mined in a browser? So I can remove the dreaded ads from my website.

Comment: Doing this will significantly increase CPU usage and power consumption on your users' devices, harming battery life if mobile, and generally annoy them. Adblockers will block mining too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Mining in your browser means mining with CPU. There are a lot of coins that focus on CPU-mining. Of course, Bitcoin is not one of them as ASIC-mining is much more effizient.

There is a useful list of coins:

> The CPU Coin List is a sortable list of Alternate Cryptocurrencies (Altcoins) that can be mined on your CPU

http://cpucoinlist.com/

By the way: Mining in the browser already happens. There is coinhive ( https://coinhive.com/ ) for example. They offer a script you can implement into the sourcecode of your website. If someone visits the site with activated javascript, the mining starts automaticly. The mined cryptocurrency is Monero.

Comment: do the coins in the above list have any disadvantage as compared to bitcoin ?
does cpu mining have any cons as compared to asic mining ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set up a Monero miner with a few lines of Javascript. You can check how to do this [here](https://mining.best/). Unless you have a lot of traffic, you are not likely to earn much. You are also harming the battery life of your users and their CPU.

Answer (score -1):

I found the perfect CPU mining coin. It started out as a proof of work coin and now currently deploys a proof of stake system.

Make sure to check out WebDollar.io

Note: WebDollar Wallets are also browser based so make sure to download and save your wallet.

Plus, the coin can be staked in the comfort of your Telegram (5%) or Reddit (6%) accounts